# How to compile C# application through Command Prompt

Tags: c#

I have one folder. In that I have three cs files.

**Demo.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Test
    {
        public static Entity entity = new Entity();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var objectHandler = Activator.CreateInstance(null,
                                                         args);
            var obj = objectHandler.Unwrap();
            entity.GetAnnotation(obj.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public void GetAnnotation(Type classname)
        {
            Attribute[] dataAnnotationlist = Attribute.GetCustomAttributes(propInfo);
            foreach (var dataannotationAttribute in dataAnnotationlist)
            {
                //some operation to get annotation property from Employee.cs class
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Employee.cs**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Demo
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [Display(Name = "name")]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have created XML file format from class file (Employee.cs) using reflection.
But error occurred when try to run through Command Prompt. It runs in visual studio.

I want to run Test.cs, Entity.cs using command prompt with passing "Employee.cs" as a string parameter to Main method.
Now, I have passed hard coded as,

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle objectHandler = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Demo.Employee");
```

Its working fine but how to pass it through command.

Error Occurred is:

> Entity.cs(8,29): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>           'DataAnnotations' does not exist in the namespace
>           'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?) Entity.cs(9,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Objects'
>           does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an
>           assembly reference?) Employee.cs(6,33): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'DataAnnotations' does
>           not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an
>           assembly reference?)

and it also shows error for "DataAnnotations" and "Objects".

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean "when try to run through Command Prompt"? Can you show command you use?

Comment: Members of the `System.Data.DataAnnotations` namespace are declared in the System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll assembly.  Is it referenced?

Comment: csc /out:Test.exe Test.cs Entity.cs Employee.cs

Comment: Yes, I have added this dll in my project but it shows error on command prompt.

Comment: I've updated title "run" -> "compile" as it looks like you actually trying to compile your files rather than run. Feel free to improve/revert.

Comment: "I have created XML file format from class file (Employee.cs) using reflection." what does that mean? how is this connected to your question? "and it also shows error for "DataAnnotations" and "Objects"." - which one is that?

Comment: I am just told that because it is my application. It is not related.

Comment: Thanks Alexei for improve my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option to simply [build .csproj with MSBUILD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393573.aspx).

More entertaining is to configure all dependencies yourself via command line arguments of csc. For your immediate error you need to add references with `/r:` command similar to following

```
 csc /out:Test.exe /r:System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll *.cs
```

For more details on command line arguments of csc check help `csc /?` or on MSDN [CSC command line options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ds95cz0.aspx) and [Building with CSC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx).

Comment: I try it working but how to pass class as parameter to Main method in Test.cs using command prompt

Comment: @user3582190 Are you looking for `test.exe arg1 ` ? How to run executable from command line and pass arguments to it would be off-topic on SO. If it is your real question - consider http://superuser.com for more info...

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Test.exe arg1 but here I am passing class name as a argument.

Comment: Test.cs "Demo.Employee"

Comment: It shows error, Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: activationContext
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationConte
xt activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, Strin
g[] activationCustomData)
   at Demo.Test.Main(String[] args)

Comment: @user3582190 I'm not exactly sure what else you've expected from your code [CreteInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130754%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you've used expects not-null as first argument and you explicitly pass null...

Comment: @user3582190  You may want to ask separate question or seriously rework this one so it is clear where you are stuck and what is your goal. Good luck.

Comment: You are not getting my point. As you told I compile project. But when I run it , I want to pass a string as a argument. But here string is a class (Employee.cs). How can I pass class as a argument ?

Comment: @user3582190 Irrespective of arguments you'll pass to your executable it will fail. Your code is essentially equivalent of `throw new NullRefferenceException();` at this point. Side note: Please ask one concrete question in one post. If you feel I suggested completely wrong thing with `csc`/`msbuild` - please downvote so I know it is wrong... But I don't see any other concrete problems mentioned in the post one can answer.